# How load assembly than run some function from it + get result and unload

Tags: .net, reflection, f#, appdomain

F# 1.9.9, OS - WinXP
I'm trying to do this by two code versions but get errors in both cases.

UPDATE.

dir on `"D:\Sources\ATProjectChecker\ATProjectChecker\tests\asms"` contains `FSharp.Core.dll` and `mscorlib.dll`

```
SerializationException: type is not allowed (my translation from russian)
 "TestLoader+cross_dlg@135,ATProjectChecker, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=null".
```

```
let load_run_unload path = 
let dlg () : unit = 
    let name = System.Reflection.AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(path)
    let asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile path
    //let asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(name.FullName)
    //let run = asm.GetType("Test").GetMethod("run")
    //let run () = run.Invoke(null, [||])
    //ignore( run() )
    ()
let dsetup = new System.AppDomainSetup()
dsetup.ApplicationBase <- @"D:\Sources\ATProjectChecker\ATProjectChecker\tests\asms" //__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__
dsetup.ShadowCopyFiles <- "true"

let evil = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence
let tmp_domain = System.AppDomain.CreateDomain("TmpDomain", evil, dsetup)

let cross_dlg = new System.CrossAppDomainDelegate( dlg )
tmp_domain.DoCallBack( cross_dlg )
```

Comment: Which version of F#? Which OS?

Comment: You want to edit your question to include that information @psct.

Answer (score 0):

`FileNotFoundException` when loading an assembly is thrown in instances where a dependent DLL could not be loaded.

Likely your real problem is one of your dependencies not `test`.

Comment: test.fs now hase structure: `module Test

let f a b =
    a,b` depending on what?

Comment: What assemblies is your test DLL dependent on? Such as `mscorlib` and `FSharp.Core`.

Comment: Ok, topic is updated now. What do I do with the SerializationException?